# Migrate IE favourites from windows server 2008 to Edge on windows server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2016, migration, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

There is a windows server 2008 with users who can configure their favourites in IE. A migration to windows server 2016 is imminent and I'd like to migrate these favourites for each user. I've tried finding googling for GPOs who can do that but ended up with nothing. Before I ask every user to somehow save their favourites and import them into their new browser, is there an automated process to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install the Edge GPOs and activate "Automatically import another browser's data and settings at first run"? This *should* do the trick.

Comment: @bjoster I activated that policy on the 2016 but the 2008 server is a different machine. How do I point to that machine? Or how do I move an export for each user of the 2008 machine to the 2016 machine, where the latter can import it from?

Comment: Just copy the /favourites/ folder from the profile.

Comment: @bjoster thanks, I figured that that could do the trick but I'm not willing to perform that task ~15.000 times.

Comment: Maybe a script would be helpful. I had to migrate around 5k users (favourites) this way; Ie uses just a folder with files, so a simple copy job was enough to get it done. Took a while, though.

Comment: @bjoster thank you but that doesn't just work like that. Edge has a different way of storing favorites than IE

Comment: the trick is to do one thing after another: If you need to import your favourites from a server where yout IE favourites have not been copied to, you need to copy them before you can let edge import them. Just copy all your IE files from "old" %userprofile% to new, *then* import them to edge. There is way to do this in one step, because Edge has a different way of storing favorites than IE.